# Get Counter most common key value

Tags: python, string, list, counter

I need to print only the key of the most common tuple returned by `most_common(1)` but it is returning a tuple. How can I get just the key?

For the given example, it should print only `The System`, now I am getting `('The System', 3)`. I wasn't able to find a function in documentation which can do that.

```
from collections import Counter

def main():

cmp_sub_list = ['System', 'System', 'The System', 'Customer', 'The System', 'The System']
most_common_subject = Counter(cmp_sub_list).most_common(1)
print(most_common_subject)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `print(most_common_subject[0][0])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the tuple index, i.e.:

```
most_common_subject = Counter(cmp_sub_list).most_common(1)[0][0]
# The System
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/50fd730c1c)

Comment: What if I need the `n` most common keys?